# Highcharts x-axis data is 3 hours apart with "Now" start point, but want full day with 0:00 start time

Tags: highcharts

just started playing with the Highcharts API and it is very impressive with lots of great documentation and demos! I am getting weather data at 3 hour intervals for five days and it works fine, but the x-axis is cluttered. I would like to make the x-axis full days regardless of the start time of the data with vertical alternateGridColor for each day.

This demo seems to be a solution, but I cannot get it to work on my data:

http://www.highcharts.com/ref/show/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/plotoptions/pointinterval-pointstart/

The demo has one series, I have four. Not sure if that is the issue.

Or I thought of "padding" the data array so it always started at 0:00 of the current day and ended at 24:00 of the fifth day.

Comment: Create jsFiddle with that issue, please. Number of series doesn't matter.

Comment: I am not up to speed on jsFiddle, but it seem like a great test system.

Comment: a link to a live page with your chart, or pasting your chart code into your question will help